# Flutter get class field value back and forth

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox widget and I'm having trouble getting the bool value of that checkbox from another class:
So am having a form in stateful widget Signup, within this form I'm calling my CustomCheckBox widget (also a stateful widget).

The issue: When I click on the checkbox its value change to true in the CustomCheckBox widget however after submitting the form in Signup widget the value always false (seams to be no back communication between the the two widgets)

My CustomCheckBox code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tunimmo/Constants/palette.dart';

class CustomCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  bool checked;
  final String label;

  CustomCheckBox({this.checked, this.label});

  @override
  _CustomCheckBoxState createState() => _CustomCheckBoxState();
}

class _CustomCheckBoxState extends State<CustomCheckBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 30, right: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: myPrimaryColor,
                ),
                child: Text("  "),
              ),
              Text('  ${widget.label}', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
            ],
          ),
          Center(
              child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                widget.checked = !widget.checked;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: widget.checked ? myPrimaryColor : myWhiteColor,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: myPrimaryColor,
                  width: 3,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                child: widget.checked
                    ? Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        size: 25.0,
                        color: myWhiteColor,
                      )
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                        size: 25.0,
                        color: myWhiteColor,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the Signup widget I'm just calling the constructor and passing a bool field (expected to send/get the value in the CustomCheckBox widget) and a string label.

PS: I have more than one checkbox in my form.

Please advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not changing the checked value in the screen(signup) but changing in the custom checkbox, to solve this issue define  `checked` variable in SignUp if not already did, then define Function call back in the `checkbox` widget as follows:

```
final Function(bool)checkChanged;  
CustomCheckBox({this.checked, this.label,this.checkedChanged});
```

then call it in ontap and give the value change

```
onTap: () {
 widget.checkedChanged(!widget.checked);
 setState(() {
   widget.checked = !widget.checked;
          });
        }
```

do the following when calling the CustomCheckbox:

```
CustomCheckBox(
checked:false,
label:'a label',
checkedChanged:(val){
checked=val;
}
)
```

and use that `checked` variable when submitting the form and that should solve your problem.